# C++ Preguntas sobre la instruccion Goto

Tags: c++, c

Estudiando programacion me tope con esta extraña instruccion, en cierta manera entiendo que salta a la instruccion a la que apunta pero ¿Por que no se usa? La verdad es una curiosa alternativa a los bucles y condicionales pero he leido que no es bueno usarla, y mis dudas son:

- ¿Por que no se usa?
- ¿Que sucede en el programa cuando se la usa?

Comment: Esa instruccion se salta comprobaciones, se salta el *flow* de ejecucion de la aplicacion... es una pesadilla.

Comment: No es una función, es una instrucción ;)

Comment: Ok Paper lo editare

Comment: Mm.. tan mala es? me parecia util de lejos aunque casi nunca he visto un programa con esta instruccion

Comment: Muchas veces no se usa y se alegan cosas como: *es que usar goto da lugar a codigo spagetti* lo cual en mi opinion es cierto el la mayoria de los casos, ademas de que muchos problemas se pueden solucionar sin usar goto, y otras tantas por el estigma que se le ha dado al uso de goto (profesores, libros, compañeros). *Que sucede al programa cuando lo usa*, si se usa bien nada, es mas el ordenador no para de hacer goto y otro tipo de saltos. La unica vez o veces que he usado goto es para crear una tabla/as de excepiones. Saludos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### ¿Por que no se usa?

Por la *ofuscación* del código que implica.

Por ejemplo, en un bucle (`do`, `while`, `for`), podemos estar seguros de que la única forma de salir se encuentra en el propio bucle; bien porqué se cumplió la condición necesaria, bien porqué usamos un `break`.

Podemos, pues, comprobar el código *hacia atrás*, sabiendo que para llegar a un punto exacto, *obligatoriamente* se ha pasado por los puntos anteriores (teniendo en cuenta los `if( ) ... else ...`, claro está).

Esto **no se cumple** en un `goto`. Si encontramos una etiqueta, un *destino* para un `goto`, **no hay forma de saber** la secuencia de instrucciones que nos llevó hasta allí. ¿ De donde venimos ? Sobre todo, si hacemos de nuestro código un *muestrario* de `goto`.

#### ¿Que sucede en el programa cuando se la usa?

Exactamente lo que esperas: saltas a la etiqueta indicada. No hay mayores efectos secundarios, ni nada malo *implicito* en usarlo, salvo lo indicado en el párrafo anterior. Si estás en un bloque `{ ... }`, las variables locales al bloque dejan de existir y, si estas en C++, los destructores son llamados correctamente; todo funciona como se espera.

Comment: muchas gracias Dolmenes, muy detallada tu explicacion

Comment: En C++ no se puede afirmar que "*no hay efectos secundarios*" al usar `goto`. De hecho, los hay: `goto` puede implicar abandonar un ámbito, el abandonar un ámbito provoca la llamada a destructores del ámbito que estamos abandonando.

Comment: eso es muy cierto

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster En mi respuesta indico `... y, si estas en C++, los destructores son llamados correctamente ...` queriendo hacer referencia a eso que indicas. Lamento que no se me entienda con claridad :-(

Answer (score 8):

La **programación estructurada** es un paradigma de programación orientado a mejorar la claridad, calidad y tiempo de desarrollo de un programa de computadora, utilizando únicamente subrutinas y tres estructuras: secuencia, selección (if y switch) e iteración (bucles for y while), **considerando innecesario y contraproducente el uso de la instrucción de transferencia incondicional (GOTO),** que podría conducir a "**código espagueti**", que es mucho más difícil de seguir y de mantener, y era la causa de muchos errores de programación.

El **código espagueti** es un término peyorativo para los programas de computación que tienen una estructura de control de flujo **compleja e incomprensible**. Su nombre deriva del hecho que este tipo de código parece asemejarse a un plato de espaguetis, es decir, un montón de hilos intrincados y anudados.

Tradicionalmente suele asociarse este estilo de programación con **lenguajes básicos y antiguos**, donde el flujo se controlaba mediante sentencias de control **muy primitivas como goto** y utilizando números de línea.

Comment: tiene sentido.. la verdad se haria un espagueti como dices

Comment: De hecho es muy parecido a lo que se hacia en ensamblador, y me parece que era una manera primitiva de las funciones

Answer (score 5):

Goto es una instrucción que realiza un salto en el flujo del programa. De la siguiente manera:

```
/*Bucle*/
int x = 0;
while(x < 100){
   if(x == 0) goto salto;
   x++;
}

salto: {
   printf("Ha sucedido un salto");
}
```

El bucle while no se ejecutaría 100 veces, sino que en la primera iteración, saltaría a la etiqueta indicada por goto.

De todas formas, esta instrucción no es muy recomendada, empeora la calidad del código y dificulta su depuración.

Comment: Ya veo, la verdad es que su implementacion es sencilla por lo que veo, gracias por el ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Por qué no se usa?

Sí se usa; es una instrucción C++ perfectamente válida, y depende del programador (y de su entorno) decidir la conveniencia o no de usarla, de acuerdo con lo que se necesite hacer y cómo prefiere hacerlo. Es como preguntar ¿Por qué no se usa break? ¿Por qué no se usa for? ¿Por qué no se usa return? Es la pregunta la que no se usa, no goto.

> ¿Qué sucede en el programa cuando se la usa?

Ocurre una transferencia de control incondicional hacia la instrucción inmediatamente siguiente a la "label" asociada. Aquí hay un ejemplo que me parece apropiado: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto