# que otras funciones le puedo agregar a este codigo de el teorema de pitagoras?

Tags: c

nesecito saber que mas le puede agregar sobre el teorema de pitagoras al codigo 
yo no soy muy bueno sobre eso y en que se aplica el teorema de pitagoras pero solo hice lo basico alguien que me diga que otra funcion le puedo agregar

Pd: diganme que tan bueno esta la estructura del codigo 
se aceptan buenas y malas criticas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x,x1,x2;
    float ca,ha,co,r,hp;
    float rh,rh2;
    float co1,ca1,rh1;
    reinicio:

    printf("por favor ingrese lo que dese hacer \n");
    printf("(1) calcular tercer lado \n");
    printf("(2) salir \n");
    scanf("%i",&x);

    if (x == 4){
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("pero primero debe asignar el valor de las variables\n");
    printf("utilice el siguiente el siguiente figura para guiarse\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("                                                     \n");
    printf("                             /|                      \n");
    printf("                            / |                      \n");
    printf("                           /  | c                    \n");
    printf("                   a      /   | a                    \n");
    printf("                  s      /    | t                    \n");
    printf("                 u      /     | e                    \n");
    printf("                n      /      | t                    \n");
    printf("               e      /       | o    =(A)            \n");
    printf("              t      /        |   a                  \n");
    printf("             t      /         |   d                  \n");
    printf("            o      /          |   y                  \n");
    printf("           p  (c) /           |   a                  \n");
    printf("          i  //  /            |   c                  \n");
    printf("         h      /             |   e                  \n");
    printf("               /              |   n                  \n");
    printf("              /               |   t                  \n");
    printf("             /                |   e                  \n");
    printf("            /                 |                      \n");
    printf("           /                  |                      \n");
    printf("          /                   |                      \n");
    printf("         /                    |                      \n");
    printf("        /                     |                      \n");
    printf("       /                      |                      \n");
    printf("      /_______________________|                      \n");
    printf("        cateto                                       \n");
    printf("             opuesto    = (B)                        \n");

    switch(x){
        case 1:
            printf("pro favor selecciones que lado desea calcular\n");
            printf("(1)calcular hipotenusa\n");
            printf("(2)calcular cateto adyacente\n");
            printf("(3)calcular cateto opuesto\n");
            scanf("%i",&x1);
            if(x1 == 1){
                printf("\n");
                printf("ingrese el numero de cateto opuesto\n");
                scanf("%f",&co);
                printf("ingrese el numero de cateto adyacente\n");
                scanf("%f",&ca);
                printf("\n");

                ca1 = pow(co,2);
                co1 = pow(ca,2);
                rh =  ca1 + co1;
                rh1 = sqrt(rh);

                printf("\n");
                printf("el resultado es: %f\n",rh1);
                printf("pero primero debe asignar el valor de las variables\n");
                printf("utilice el siguiente el siguiente figura para guiarse\n");
                printf("\n");
                printf("                                                     \n");
                printf("                             /|                      \n");
                printf("                            / |                      \n");
                printf("                           /  | c                    \n");
                printf("                          /   | a                    \n");
                printf("                         /    | t                    \n");
                printf("            a           /     | e                    \n");
                printf("           s           /      | t                    \n");
                printf("          u           /       | o   = %f\n",ca);
                printf("         e           /        |   a                  \n");
                printf("        t           /         |   d                  \n");
                printf("       o           /          |   y                  \n");
                printf("      p  %f",rh1);printf(" /           |   a                  \n");
                printf("     i  //       /            |   c                  \n");
                printf("    h           /             |   e                  \n");
                printf("               /              |   n                  \n");
                printf("              /               |   t                  \n");
                printf("             /                |   e                  \n");
                printf("            /                 |                      \n");
                printf("           /                  |                      \n");
                printf("          /                   |                      \n");
                printf("         /                    |                      \n");
                printf("        /                     |                      \n");
                printf("       /                      |                      \n");
                printf("      /_______________________|                      \n");
                printf("        cateto                                       \n");
                printf("             opuesto  = %f\n",co);

                printf("\n");
                printf("Quiere volver a ejecutar el programa?\n ");
                printf("(1)si\n");
                printf("(2)no\n");
                scanf("%i",&x);

                if (x == 1){
                    system("cls");
                    goto reinicio;
                }
                if (x == 2){
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            if(x1 == 2){
                printf("\n");
                printf("ingrese el numero de cateto opuesto\n");
                scanf("%f",&co);
                printf("ingrese el numero de la hipotenusa\n");
                scanf("%f",&hp);
                printf("\n");

                ca1 = pow(co,2);
                co1 = pow(hp,2);
                rh =  ca1 - co1;
                rh1 = sqrt(rh);

                printf("el resultado es: %f",rh1);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*se aceptan buenas y malas criticas*". Agarrate, que vienen curvas. 1) Decide si quieres usar C o C++, son lenguajes distintos y has etiquetado la pregunta con ambos, tu código no tiene nada de C++. 2) Evita las variables de nombres cortos, causan confusión. 3) Evita repetir código, tienes las rutinas de pintado, obtención de datos y muestra de resultados repetidas dos veces. 4) Un `switch` sobre un solo valor no tiene sentido. 5) Evita usar [`goto`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52197/c-preguntas-sobre-la-instruccion-goto).

Comment: 6) Crea un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (el tuyo tiene 136 líneas) describiendo tu **problema de programación**. 7) He leído tu pregunta tres veces, aún no se que preguntas.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: "respondiendo a tus criticas"  1)me equivoque al etiquetar. 2)en lo personal yo me guio mas facil y rapido con variables cortas. 3)ok eso si ya no lo boy a hacer. 4)es que ademas de calcular el tercer lado tenia pensado otras opciones, por eso la pregunta (pero no debi haber escrto  funcion  tenia que poner que otra opcion para elegir);

Comment: "*en lo personal yo me guio mas fácil y rápido con variables cortas*". Esto es un gran error. Por dos motivos: 1) Como programador posiblemente trabajarás con otros programadores así que un código fuente no es para tu propio consumo exclusivo, ergo: no hagas las cosas que **personalmente** te sean más cómodas si no las que **generalmente** sean menos ambiguas. 2) Tal vez hoy te parezca buena idea usar nombres cortos para las variables, pero revisa tu código en unos meses y seguramente te resulte un galimatías incomprensible, hazte un favor a ti y a la comunidad: usa nombres auto-explicativos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster pero tampoco se debe usar tan largos. En mi opinion, es mejor escribir `lado` en vez de `x` pero seria un error de estilo usar `ladoSegundoDelTrianguloRectangulo`. No obstante, si tenemos solo dos clases en nuestro codigo, cliente y restaurante , me parece que esta bien llamar las instancias `r1`, `r2` y `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo explorar que capacidades a la hora de operar tiene la programación en C, obviamente con los datos que das y algunos mas podrías conocer el angulo de los vértices, entre otros.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar cualquier funcion que encuentres en un libro de trigonometria. La programacion es una actividad creativa, use su imaginacion.

Por ejemplo, en el caso 2 puedes verificar que el tamano del cateto no es mas grande que el tamano de la hipotenusa.

```
if (cateto >= hipotenusa){
    printf("ERROR: cateto >= hipotenusa\n");
}
```

Tambien puedes invitar al usuario a introducir 3 numeros para que el codigo verifique si forman un triangulo rectangulo.

Comment: Julián, tu respuesta luce mas como un comentario, si es una respuesta, debes mejorarla de acuerdo a lo que dice el Centro de Ayuda del sitio: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).