# ¿Es válido usar break en estructuras de control repetitivas?

Tags: c++, buenas-prácticas

Recientemente, he estado viendo varios ejemplos de código en C++ donde se tiene algo como lo siguiente:

```
//líneas de código
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   if((alguna_condición))
   {
      //más código
      break;
   }
}
//siguen más líneas de código
```

En mis clases de C++ solo he utilizado la instrucción `break` con la estructura condicional `switch` y por eso me sorprendió un poco el uso de `break` con la estructura repetitiva `for`. Buscando en Google encontré [los](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3217425/8781554) [siguientes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3922599/8781554) [enlaces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/58237/286011), sin embargo lo único que he conseguido es confundirme. Según lo que he leído, para algunos usar `break` no tiene nada de malo, pero para otros es tan malo como usar el [infame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/52197/63114) `goto`.

Básicamente, mi pregunta, como indica el título, es si es correcto usar `break` en estructuras de control repetitivas, y en caso de que no, ¿es tan "dañino" como usar `goto`?.

Gracias de antemano por comentarios y/o respuestas.

Comment: En general, mucho menos que infame o dañino es suficiente para que el comité estándar elimine una característica del lenguaje (esa fue la suerte de `auto_ptr` o la especificación de excepciones en funciones). Si hubiera algo de dañino o infame en goto, ya no estaría ahí, aunque lo sigan repitiendo los más listillos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es perfectamente válido; esa es su misión, *salir* del bloque de código actual; mas concretamente, su uso se limita a los bloques:

- `switch`
- `do`
- `while`
- `for`

**No** es válido para *salir* de bloques `if` (que no estén contenidos en alguno de los bloques anteriores):

```
if( x ) {
  if( x == 5 ) break; // INCORRECTO.
```

Ni **tampoco** para *scopes* anónimos (igualmente, que no estén contenidos en ninguno de los bloques válidos):

```
{
  int z = 2;
  break; // INCORRECTO.
```

**Tampoco** permite salir de bloques *anidados*:

```
while( x ) {
  while( y ) {
    if( y == 5 )
      break;
  }
  // el break nos manda aquí; solo el bloque interior.
}
```

En ese ejemplo, `break` *sale* del bloque **mas interno**; es decir, solo funciona **para el bloque en el que está incluido**.

Answer (score 5):

> Según lo que he leído, para algunos usar `break` no tiene nada de malo.

Usar `break` es tan malo como usar cualquier otra utilidad de C++: nada malo. La *maldad* no está en la utilidad usada si no en el uso que se le da. Tal y como has señalado suele usarse para alterar el flujo natural de un bucle, por ejemplo iterando una colección hasta dar con un elemento concreto:

`Ejemplo1`

```
int indice = 0;
for (const int final = principes.size(); indice != final; ++indice)
{
    // Eres tu mi principe azul que yo sonye?
    if (es_azul(principes[indice])
        break;
}
```

El código anterior no tiene nada de malo: recorre una colección de objetos (`principes`) a los que les realiza un test (`es_azul`) y al finalizar el bucle la variable `indice` contiene el índice del primer objeto que cumpla dicha condición o `principes.size()` en caso de no haber ninguno; el código anterior es casi equivalente a este:

`Ejemplo2`

```
int indice = 0;
bool encontrado = false;
for (const int final = principes.size(); !encontrado && (indice != final); ++indice)
{
    // Eres tu mi principe azul que yo sonye?
    encontrado = es_azul(principes[indice]);
}
```

Pueden haber acalorados debates sobre cuál de las dos versiones es mejor pero en general, estas discusiones no se centrarán en el uso de `break` si no en cantidad de instrucciones (el bucle de `Ejemplo2` da una vuelta más) o claridad (`Ejemplo1` puede ser más difícil de entender).

Sea cual sea el caso, dificilmente verás `Ejemplo1` o `Ejemplo2` en C++ moderno pues lo habitual será delegar este tipo de operaciones a la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm):

```
auto azul = std::find_if(principes.begin(), principes.end(),
            [](const auto &principe){ return es_azul(principe); });
bool encontrado = (azul != principes.end());
```

Cada compilador implementará [`std::find_if`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) de `<algorithm>` a su manera pero en general la implementación podría parecerse a:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
InputIt find_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (p(*first)) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

La instrucción `return first;` del interior del bucle funciona de manera parecida a los `break` que pones en tu ejemplo: alteran el flujo natural del bucle y como puedes ver se usa en código de librerías estándar, nada que objetar ¿verdad?

Comment: Gracias a su respuesta y a la del user Trauma tengo las cosas más claras. Solo una consulta (quizás sea motivo de otra pregunta), pero aquí va: leyendo también sobre lo de break encontré el llamado principio SESE y para algunos el que haya más de un return no es correcto porque viola el principio anterior. Tal parece entonces que en C++ no existe (y creo que tampoco en otro lenguaje) una programación estructurada al 100℅, verdad?

Comment: La pregunta sobre el uso y abuso de `return` [ha sido ya respondida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/69971/2742), échale un vistazo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yo voy a ser la voz disonante: aunque `break` (y `continue`, otra operación que muchas veces entra en el mismo saco que `break`) es técnicamente válido y puede usarse para salir de estructuras condicionales/iterativas, si se puede evitar, no debería usarse para eso en programación de alto nivel (con algunas excepciones). Parte clave: "*si se puede evitar*".

No es tan malo (¿o debería decir [dañino](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf)?) como el `goto` porque sabes exactamente a dónde vas a ir cuando haces un `break` (al final del bloque que lo contiene), pero con él se está rompiendo el flujo normal de la estructura lo cual tampoco es ideal, hace el código menos legible (aunque esto se puede debatir) y puede llevar a resultados inesperados.

Por ejemplo, si estás revisando el siguiente código y llegas a la cabecera del `for`, esperarás que cuando termine el bucle, el valor de `x` sea mayor o igual a 100. Algo que no va a ocurrir porque N líneas más abajo hay un `break`:

```
for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  ...
  i = funcion1(x);
  j = funcion2();
  k = i + j + x;
  ...
  if (k >= 25) break;
}
```

El verdadero problema viene porque la gente no los usa bien y abusa de ellos. Por ejemplo, en el caso anterior en el que hay un `break` dentro de un bucle `for`, lo que realmente ocurre es que no se ha seleccionado la estructura correcta: se podría evitar el `break` refactorizando el código a un bucle `while` o un `do...while`:

```
do {
  ...
  i = funcion1(x);
  j = funcion2();
  k = i + j + x;
  ...
  x++;
} while (x < 100 && k < 25);
```

Otro problema con `break`, [como indica Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125907/250), surge si tienes dos estructuras iterativas anidadas donde sólo se va a salir de la interna, pero ¿y si queríamos salir de las dos? ¿hacemos un segundo `break`? ¿volvemos a hacer comprobaciones? En ese caso, quizás sería mejor usar una variable centinela, por ejemplo.

---

Resumiendo: tanto `break` como `continue` son técnicamente válidos (y en algunos casos hasta necesarios) y pueden funcionar perfectamente bien en un código limpio y ordenado... pero ese no siempre es el caso, y su uso (o abuso) puede llevar a problemas y malas prácticas.

Comment: En el primer caso también podría hacerse `for (x = 0; x < 25; x++) {` Y en el segundo estaría muy bien usar `goto`

Comment: @asdasdasd es un ejemplo muy simple para ilustrar un problema. Si la condición de parada fuera el resultado de una función o de otros cálculos, no sería tan sencillo como hacer un `for` con x<25

Comment: @asdasdasd como ponía en otro comentario: también se pueden poner clavos a golpes con unos alicates, y el resultado final sería el mismo que hacerlo con un martillo, pero eso no es para lo que se crearon. Las diferentes estructuras de control de un lenguaje de programación tienen su propia funcionalidad y utilidad; se pueden utilizar para simular otras, pero entonces no se estarán usando para lo que se crearon.

Comment: @asdasdasd sobre el goto: se puede usar para casi todo y para simular todas las estructuras de control... pero si ya estás usando un lenguaje que las tiene, ¿por qué usar el goto para simular un for o un while? El uso de goto fuera de programación a (muy) bajo nivel es de dudosa utilidad y es una señal de programación spaghetti. Estamos en el siglo XXI y no en la década de los 1960.

Comment: En realidad mi comentario tenia la sola intención de señalar mi disconformidad con tus opiniones, y usé tus mismos ejemplos para mostrar que pueden también usarse para mostrar opiniones opuestas. No veo que expongas argumentos técnicos para sustentarlas sino más bien parece la reafirmación de prejuicios tratando de sustentarlos en falacias. Por ejemplo, "Break no es tan malo como goto" es doblemente falso: Break no es malo, tampoco goto, no importa cuántas vece lo repitas. A modo de simplificación: si fuera así ya no estarían, ¿o crees que al comité estándar se les ha pasado?

Comment: @asdasdasd No se les ha pasado obviamente, pero eso no quiere decir que sea bueno o adecuado usarlo (en MISRA 2012 se recomienda no usarlo y se prohíbe para algunos casos). Dijkstra decía de no usarlo directamente y Knuth (el principal valedor de su uso o el más eminente) decía de usarlo... pero solo en ciertos casos. Es un debate que lleva 50 años y, aunque teóricamente se pueda seguir usando, en la práctica el uso de goto es marginal dentro de los lenguajes de alto nivel y más un legado de otro tiempo que una realidad práctica.

Comment: A favor: Stroustrup, en "The C++ Programming Language IV" (# 9.6) dice que `goto` es de escaso uso en la programación de alto nivel, pero que es de gran utilidad en otros casos. Y en particular, prácticamente usa tu mismo ejemplo para mostrar de qué manera `goto` es una buena opción. No estoy haciendo un alegato incondicional a favor de `goto`, no quisiera caer en tu mismo error por reciprocidad, pero creo que la opinión de Stroustrup no pude estar tan equivocada.

Comment: @asdasdasd parte clave: “en la programación de alto nivel”. Claro que es importante en la programación a bajo nivel (cómo ponía en otro comentario arriba), pero a más alto nivel el goto no tiene tanto sentido porque ya existen estructuras de control que van a manejar y controlar el flujo del programa mejor y con menos fallos (humanos).

Comment: Ahora que releo, la parte de alto/bajo nivel la pongo solo en los comentarios y no en la respuesta en sí. Debería editar para añadir eso.

Comment: Por favor, toma mi comentario como una invitación a leer a Stroustrup, que probablemente no me haya sabido expresar con eficacia.  Yo entiendo que "de escaso uso" quiere decir que se usa en escasas oportunidades, y su ejemplo de cuándo en la programación de alto nivel se usa acertadamente es ni más ni menos que el ejemplo que tú usas para denostarlo. Pero no te dejes confundir por mi torpeza, lee a Stroustrup.

Comment: Lo releeré (tuve que leer el libro en la universidad hace ya mucho tiempo, me hago mayor). Lee sobre la crisis del software de los 60.