# Porque no usar if dentro de un ciclo for

Tags: java, c, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

Hola mi pregunta es esta:

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
```

dado un ejemplo como cualquiera como este donde tengo un `if` dentro de un ciclo `for`, el profesor me dijo:

1) Un `if` no debe ir dentro de un `for` porque no estas entendiendo la esencia del `for` y para compensarlo pusiste el `if`, lo que deberías poner es un `while`.

2) La esencia del `for` es repetir el numero de veces según la condición dada en su bloque y lo que estas haciendo es cortando el ciclo con un `return`, (cosa que no se debe hacer al igual con un `break`)

Entonces, ¿por qué muchos códigos tienen un `if` dentro de un `for`?

Comment: Las respuestas a esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125903/63114) tal vez aclaren tu duda.

Comment: Entonces me podrías dar un ejemplo de como puedo mejorar este código, ya que según entendí ese "return False" funciona como un "break" de corto de control. Aunque no hubo la respuesta de usar un declaración "if" dentro de un "for" esta mal.

Comment: Mira mi respuesta en ese enlace. Hay un caso igual al que expones (pero con `break`). El problema no es que haya `if`s dentro de un bucle `for`, eso es normal; el problema surge cuando ese `if` se usa para romper el flujo normal del bucle. Es una señal de que quizás el bucle seleccionado no sea la estructura correcta y, aunque técnicamente válido, es código que no termina de oler bien (_code smell_).

Comment: hola me podrías dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo en este código así me queda más claro. ¿Entonces todo lo podría hacer con un "While"?

Comment: No es que todo se pueda hacer con un `while`. La idea es que, aunque se pueda, cada estructura tiene una utilidad y funcionalidad y debería usarse acorde a ello. Por ejemplo: puedes usar unos alicates para darle golpes a un clavo y ponerlo en la pared, pero para eso ya existen los martillos. Sí, va a funcionar y el resultado acaba siendo el mismo... pero no es la mejor manera.

Comment: Y en el caso de la pregunta quizás un `while (i < n && n % i != 0) { ... }` deja más claras las condiciones de parada del bucle y su objetivo, que un `for` con `break`/`return` dentro.

Comment: ...y en este punto no sé si poner los comentarios como respuesta o marcar la pregunta como duplicada de la otra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Un if no debe ir dentro de un for porque no estas entendiendo la esencia del for y para compensarlo pusiste el if, lo que deberías poner es un while.

Una respuesta demasiado genérica para ser cierta.

Quizás para el ejemplo que muestras el uso del `if` sea excesivo, ya que podrías conseguir exactamente lo mismo sin usar estructuras de control adicionales:

```
bool ok = true;
for( int i=2; i<n && ok; i++ )
  ok = ((n % i) == 0);
return ok;
```

Pero es perfectamente legal usar un `if` dentro de un `for` (si no tu código no compilaría) y, como he comentado, a veces es recomendable o incluso necesario... ¿Cómo recorrerías si no un array de números y hacer una operación diferente en función de si el número es par o impar?:

```
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
  if( coleccion[i] % 2 == 0 )
  {
    // operaciones para numeros pares
  }
  else
  {
    // operaciones para numeros impares
  }
}
```

Lo que realmente quiere decir tu profesor es que, como norma general, no está bien visto que una función tenga varios puntos de salida ya que esto dificulta su depuración (Si revisas un poco el código que has puesto verás que tiene 2 `return`, es decir, dos puntos de salida diferentes). Eso sí, es importante remarcar eso de *como norma general* ya que en ocasiones es preferible tener varios puntos de salida por simple legibilidad (pero esto es ya una opinión personal).

Así, yo preferiría tener esto:

```
if( !/* chequeo 1 */ )
  return;

// operaciones ...

if( !/* chequeo 2 */ )
  return;

// operaciones ...

if( !/* chequeo 3 */ )
  return;

// operaciones ...
```

A esto:

```
if( /* chequeo 1 */ )
{
  // operaciones ...

  if( /* chequeo 2 */ )
  {
    // operaciones ...

    if( /* chequeo 3 */ )
    {
      // operaciones ...
    }
  }
}
```

Básicamente porque un código con un número excesivo de indentaciones es complicado de leer... llega un momento que no es facil saber cual es la llave de cierre de un bloque y hacer modificaciones puede ser una tarea bastante delicada. Pero como te he comentado, este punto es algo personal y habrá programadores que no compartan mi punto de vista.

Comment: hola hay algún libro que te explique temas relacionados a como usar adecuadamente cada estructura de forma adecuada.

Comment: @neoprox es que no hay una regla fija y definida sobre cómo usar adecuadamente cada estructura... lo importante (o lo que debería ser importante) es que el código sea lo más legible posible (asumiendo que debe funcionar)

Answer (score 5):

Hay dos puntos, la cuestión del `if` y la cuestión del punto adicional de salidad el `if`, con aspectos de rendimiento y legibilidad.

### Rendimiento

En todo caso parece relacionado con la técnica del *loop unrolling*.

Resumiendo, un procesador no ejecuta una instrucción en una sola fase, sino en varias. Así que, para mejorar el rendimiento, va "adelantando trabajo" y empieza a trabajar en las siguientes instrucciones antes de terminar las que ya tiene en marcha<sup>1</sup>. Además, hay otras dependencias (una instrucción necesita datos que calcula una instrucción anterior).

Esto causa problemas con los saltos, porque el procesador no sabe qué instrucción será la que se ejecutará. Se suele optar por escoger una de las posibles opciones y, si resulta que no se cumple, "eliminar" las instrucciones a medio ejecutar<sup>2</sup>, pero supone una pérdida de rendimiento.

Una de las opciones es intentar hacer predicciones basado en rendimiento anterior<sup>3</sup>, pero hay técnicas auxiliares y una de ellas es el *loop unrolling*.

Esta se basa en "desenrrollar" el bucle y hacer que cada iteración se programe como varios. Por ejemplo

```
for(int i = 0; i < miArray.size; i++) {
   acumulado += miArray[i];
}
```

realmente acaba convertido en:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (miArray.size /3) * 3; i = i+3) {
  acumulado += miArray[i];
  acumulado2 += miArray[i + 1];
  acumulado3 += miArray[i + 2];
}
acumulado += acumulado2 + acumulado3;
```

más código adicional para tratar con los últimos datos del array.

Esto no solo reduce el número de saltos, sino que también da más libertad al compilador para reorganizar las instrucciones de forma que las dependencias de datos no "bloqueen" el *pipeline*.

Naturalmente, cuando más complicada sea la lógica de los bucles y más posibles puntos de salida existan, más difícil para el compilador optimizar el bucle de esta forma. Eso hacía que los `for` fueran tradicionalmente bastante más rígidos que los `while`, para poder aprovechar esta ventaja; por ejemplo no se podía modificar el valor de la condición dentro del bloque que se ejecutaba.

Realmente, no puedo decirte hasta qué punto los procesadores siguen necesitando (y los compiladores usando) `*loop unrolling* y hasta qué punto un código como el tuyo supone un problema para un compilador moderno si quiere hacer una optimización, pero me sorprendería que significara una diferencia significativa.

### Legibilidad

Si que es correcto que la costumbre hace que, cuando ves un `for`, esperes que la ejecución no dependa de nada que no sea lo que defines en el propio `for` (y por lo tanto, esperas que se itere sobre todos los elementos).

En tu código no es difícil de ver el *break*, pero en bloques más grandes se puede pasar por alto.

**TL/DR** El problema con los `if` parece un remanente de tiempos pasados; pero sí que aconsejaría que, si vas a usar `break` o salir de forma "inesperada", uses un while por legibilidad.

---

<sup>1</sup>Esto se llama *pipelining*.

<sup>2</sup>Esto está relacionado con una vulnerabilidad recientemente descubierta.

<sup>3</sup>Normalmente el salto de un bucle se ejecutará muchas veces, y solo una vez no se ejecutará.

Answer (score 4):

El problema no es que haya `if`s dentro de un bucle `for`, eso es normal; el problema surge cuando ese `if` se usa para romper el flujo normal del bucle. Es una señal de que quizás el bucle seleccionado no sea la estructura correcta y, aunque técnicamente válido, es código que no termina de oler bien (*code smell*).

No es que no se pueda hacer con un `for` y que tengas que usar `while`. La idea es que, aunque se pueda, **cada estructura tiene una utilidad y funcionalidad y debería usarse acorde a ella**. Por ejemplo: puedes usar unos alicates para darle golpes a un clavo y ponerlo en la pared, pero para eso ya existen los martillos. Sí, va a funcionar y el resultado acabará siendo el mismo... pero no es la mejor manera.

Y en el caso de la pregunta, quizás un `while` como éste:

```
while (i<n && n%i!=0) { 
    ... 
    i++;
}
```

Sería más *natural* porque deja más claras las condiciones de parada del bucle y su objetivo, que un `for` con `break`/`return` dentro... aunque el tema de la legibilidad es relativo porque lo que es fácil de leer para uno, puede no serlo para otro.